# Solve DX+XD = B , D is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question to solve for X, Given D is a diagonal matrix and $d_{ii} + d_{jj} \ne 0$ for all *i* and *j*.
I have only been able to premultiply with  $D^{-1}$ and get
$X + D^{-1}XD = D^{-1}B$
How to solve this for X?

Comment: hint: Do you know something about commutativity of the product by a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try to express each $b_{ij}$ in terms of the entries of $X$ and $D$.

Comment: Oops sorry, I missed to write it correct.
$[DX+XD]^T = [DX^T+X^TD]$  
This makes the equation $[X+X^T]=D^{-1}B$  
And this leads to $X = 1/2[D^{-1}B]$
Does this make sense?

Comment: Oops, it is just the sum that is equal >< and not individual terms. Hmm, so how to go ahead with this?

Comment: @BSR As stated in the hint, express each entry of $B$ in terms of the entries of $X$ and $D$.

Comment: I have expressed as stated in the hint and it gives $b_{ij} = (d_{ii}+d_{jj})x_{ij}$

Comment: @BSR That's it, you have solved it

Comment: Thank you @user1551